# Are there any drawbacks to using all-lowercase file names in an ASP.NET Core project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm about to port my web site, which currently uses all-lowercase file names for everything, to ASP.NET Core.  When I look at example code and open source projects, I see that everything seems to use mixed case (e.g. MyClass.cs rather than myclass.cs).  The latter seems like it could have some benefits.  For example, considering that client-side JavaScript code generally uses all-lowercase and certain files such as project.json do by convention, it would eliminate confusion as to what capitalization to use for what file, especially if the project were ever to be browsed on a case-sensitive file system.  Are there any drawbacks to this approach, any reason why it doesn't ever seem to be done?

Comment: I generally have script files all lower case, code that is going to be compiled should stay camel case.  It's only the devs who are gonna see the source anyway.

Comment: Also, default view name is based on related controller name so for some file the capitalization would be important. **For consistency and to allows automatic renaming of a class when file is renamed from `Solution Explorer`, it is usually recommended to use file name that is the same as the class name.** A good habit is to usually have one file per class.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding referenced files in the solution should not matter.

C# however can have some case sensitive parts to it so you might want to have a read of this [Why is C# Case Sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494561/why-is-c-sharp-case-sensitive) just to be sure no other issues are there from lowercase variables etc.