# C# "Is a 'Type' but is used like a variable"

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, variables

I'm looking for some help with the following error:

> 'Practical_2.Card' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

This is my code:

```
class Tester
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Card[] hand = {
                          new Card("Spade", 3),
                          new Card("Club", 10),
                          new Card("Diamond", 11),
                          new Card("Heart", 9),
                          new Card("Diamond", 13),
                      };
        ProcessHand(hand);

    }//end of static void main

    static void ProcessHand(Card[] cards)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-10:s}: {1,-10:i}", "suit: ", Card[0]);

    }//end of static void processhand
}//end of class Tester
class Card
{
    public string suit { get; set; }
    public int facevalue { get; set; }
    public Card (string su, int fa) 
    {
        suit = su;
        facevalue = fa;

    }
    public void DisplayCard()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(suit, facevalue);

    }
}//end of class Card
```

I get the error on this line:`Console.WriteLine("{0,-10:s}: {1,-10:i}", "suit: ", Card[0]);`

Help would me much appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Card[0]` should be `cards[0]` - `Card` is a type, as the compiler is telling you, your array is named `cards`.

Comment: Awesome thank you :) i did actually try that but was presented with "suit:     : Practical_2.Card" when I ran the code. Guess something else is wrong :P

Comment: By default the `ToString` method (which is what is invoked when you pass the `Card` instance to `Console.WriteLine` returns the name of the class - if you want to print the `suit` of the `Card` at position `0` of your `cards` array you should use `cards[0].suit`.

Answer (score 1):

You want this instead:

```
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-10:s}: {1,-10:i}", "suit: ", cards[0]);
```

`Card` is a type (a class), where as `cards` is your variable, an array begin passed into the function.

Answer (score -1):

As preston and sovemp mentioned your error is because of a typo, and it's because C# is case sensitive.

If you wanna know more, check this awesome answer from another stackoverflow question [Why is C# Case Sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494561/why-is-c-sharp-case-sensitive)

Comment: First half should be vote/flag to close as typo, second half could be comment (if you'd not believe the error is typo in a first place).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks!, I'm still somewhat new to how stackoverflow works.