# Entity Framework can't properly create model from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have some database that goes quite against most standards (e.g. some tables have no PKs, some FKs point nowhere...). One entity, let's call it entity1 has several fields, field1, Field2 and field_3.

For some reason, when I try to map it, field1 comes OK, Field2 gives me an error and field_3 is okay as well.

Field2 has been mapped as follows:

```
public virtual DbSet<field2> field2 { get; set; }
```

Manually editing it like this works and fixes the problem altogether:

```
public virtual DbSet<Field2> field2 { get; set; }
```

However I don't know why EF fails to build it correctly, since it's technically reading from the database and there's no other issue related to that. This also belongs to the auto-generated file that contains entities to work with, so I'm a bit afraid my changes might break something, on top of the file being automatically regenerated every time someone updates the model from the database.

Thanks in advance.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace MyProject.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Field2
    {
        public int IdFoo { get; set; }
        public int IdBar { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdSomething { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Idwhatever { get; set; }
        public string Blah { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> idBleh { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the source code for your `field2` class and `Field2` class.

Comment: @mjwills I don't know what the code would help with, it's an auto-generated file by EF. I'll add it to the OP because it doesn't look good on comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Turns out EF6 is plagued with errors including this one.

For this reason, they stopped supporting Database-first models and incentivated Code-first approaches instead of auto-generated classes.

In short, move on to EF Core if you can and use Code-first as your go-to procedure.

Answer (score 0):

```
public virtual DbSet<field2> field2 { get; set; }
```

In your above code the first `field2` referenced there is a `Type` while the second is a `property / variable` (see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/) for the difference between `variable` and `Type`).

The reason that:

```
public virtual DbSet<field2> field2 { get; set; }
```

doesn't compile is that you don't have a class called `field2` in your codebase.

The reason that:

```
public virtual DbSet<Field2> field2 { get; set; }
```

does compile is that you do have a class called `Field2` in your codebase. The typename is [case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494561/why-is-c-sharp-case-sensitive).

Comment: Thank you. I already know that, the actual question is why EF fails to map the database correctly so I don't have to fix it manually. The code that prompts errors was auto-generated by EF and it's never happened to me before. I've been working with this framework for almost a year now by the way.

Comment: Just to make myself clear, notice the auto-generated class source code states I shall NOT MANIPULATE THIS FILE, but it's broken by default.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. If you create a completely new project and recreate the EF mappings does it work there?

Comment: I made a new project just to test, this time I only added the few references I would need for an EF project. Long story short, it still doesn't work. For some reason this table's name has a capital letter in its name and it's not parsed correctly. An early guess on my side would be the MySQL Connector/net has this little bug and it fails to map capital letters? I might be able to test it tomorrow, but it looks like that might be the case.